# MongoDB Query For Nested Grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 3 collections:

1. Plan
2. Business Process
3. Recovery Strategy

The three of them store their Primary Key in `_id` and

I have another collection: `planRecoveryStrategy` which stores

1. `planId`
2. `businessProcessId`
3. `recoveryStrategyId`

Example documents stored in `planRecoveryStrategy`:

```
{   "planId" : "PLN1",
    "processId" : "PCS1",
    "strategyId" : "RES1"
}

{   "planId" : "PLN1",
    "processId" : "PCS2",
    "strategyId" : "RES1"
}

{   "planId" : "PLN1",
    "processId" : "PCS2",
    "strategyId" : "RES2"
}
```

What is the query to write to get given the `planId` is 'PCS1'

```
{   "planId" : "PLN1",
    "processes" : [{
      "processId":"PCS1",
      "processData":{<data from Business Process Dictionary for PCS1>},
      "strategies":[{<data from Recovery Strategy Dictionary for RES1>}]
    },
    {
      "processId":"PCS2",
      "processData":{<data from Business Process Dictionary for PCS1>},
      "strategies":[{<data from Recovery Strategy Dictionary for RES1>}, 
                    {<data from Recovery Strategy Dictionary for RES2>}]
    }]
}
```

from `planRecoveryStrategy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it for grouping data:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                planId: "$planId",
                processId: "$processId"
            },
            strategies: { $addToSet: "$strategyId" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.planId",
            planId: { $first: "$_id.planId" },
            processes: {
                $addToSet: {
                    processId: "$_id.processId",
                    strategies: "$strategies"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

With sort:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "strategyId": -1 } },
    { $sort: { "processId": 1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                planId: "$planId",
                processId: "$processId"
            },
            strategies: { $addToSet: "$strategyId" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.planId",
            planId: { $first: "$_id.planId" },
            processes: {
                $addToSet: {
                    processId: "$_id.processId",
                    strategies: "$strategies"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

With including other collections:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "strategyId": -1 } },
    { $sort: { "processId": 1 } },
    {
        $lookup:
          {
            from: "BusinessProcess",
            localField: "processId", 
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "BusinessProcesses"
          }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
          {
            from: "RecoveryStrategy",
            localField: "strategyId", 
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "RecoveryStrategy"
          }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                planId: "$planId",
                processId: "$processId",
                processData: { $arrayElemAt : ["$BusinessProcesses" , 0] },
            },
            strategies: { $addToSet: "$RecoveryStrategy" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.planId",
            planId: { $first: "$_id.planId" },
            processes: {
                $addToSet: {
                    processId: "$_id.processId",
                    processData: "$_id.processData",
                    strategies: "$strategies"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: How do I select the details of the record from `Recovery Strategy` collection and store it in `strategies` array ?

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But the requirement changed a bit

Comment: @PrateekNarendra I added example with including other collections. Replace `foreignField` and `from` attributes.